# What is the right way to deploy static react app serverlessly on Azure?

Tags: reactjs, azure, serverless, azure-blob-storage

I have created a container on Azure Blob Storage and deployed my React app build in $web.

Following is my config:

[image]

This means that my default page is index.html. Also my error page is index.html.
Now when I try to open [www.MyWebUrl.com](http://www.MyWebUrl.com), it opens right and displays the content. However, when I navigate to any other relative path let's say [www.MyWebUrl.com/dashboard](http://www.MyWebUrl.com/dashboard), the container thinks that it is an error since there is no directory as "dashboard", so it throws 404. Now since my errors are also mapped to index.html, container returns index.html which successfully displays the "/dashboard".

However, due to this error first and then display, a 404 appears in network call.

[image]

How do I avoid this 404, while still being serverless with react app?